# Disable IP fragmentation on cisco port

Tags: cisco, switch, router, mtu

We are getting many `IP Fragmentation` attack. Our server only dealing with UDP RTP traffic so i wonder can we set `don't fragment` configuration so switch or cisco router port drop all packet instead of sending them to Server and server get overload to reassemble them.

I know IP Fragmentation is very important but in our case we are only handling RTP UDP traffic and packet size is very small.. so i doubt we need IP Fragmentation feature.

Comment: Do you have a firewall?  What kind of Cisco router?  If the attack sources are few, I would block them entirely.  If you block fragments, they will likely try another attack.

Comment: We don't have metal firewall but we are using `iptables` on servers. its not a single source, its DDoS so random spoofed source addresses. I just want to say `Don't Fragment` on Router or switch.. is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the external interface of your router, use this ACL:

```
access-list extended NO_FRAG
deny ip any any fragments
permit ip any any
end

interface <ext interface>
ip access-group NO_FRAG in
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inbound ACL to block fragments. The following link is a good place to start:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/generic-routing-encapsulation-gre/8014-acl-wp.html

Answer (score 1):

"Configure ASA to drop any IP fragments it receives as follows:

```
ASA# conf t
ASA(config)# fragment chain 1
ASA(config)# exit
```

Caution: Please note that this can be configured globally only, so it will affect all user traffic passing across the ASA, not only traffic specifically directed toward the Cisco ASA CX module. This configuration will result in all IP fragments being dropped by the ASA, even if this traffic will not be handled by the ASA CX module."

https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20170125-cas?emailclick=CNSemail